# ASP.Net Page Not Posting Back - Reloading Instead

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, postback

I have a simple ASP.Net login page. When the login button is clicked, the page should post back and the even should be handled by my server-side event handler. Instead, the page simply reloads. `Page.IsPostBack` is **`false`**.

I've put breakpoints in the Page_Load/Init (where applicable) handlers of the Master page, the ASPX page and the UserControl (ascx). When I hit the Login button, instead of getting a post back and having my event handler called, I simply get the page load as if it was a fresh request.

But that's not the end of it! The login page takes a single query string parameter: `Login.aspx?id=123456`. The above failure occurs when using this parameter. However, if I enable *URL Rewriting* in order to make the query `Login/123456`, the error does **not** occur; I get a post back and my event handler is called in this instance.

So why am I not getting the expected behaviour from my page? What about the rewritten URL is making the problem go away?

Login Button is declared in `LoginUserControl.ascx`:

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitLinkButton" runat="server" Text='Log In' OnClick="SubmitLinkButton_Click"></asp:Button>
```

And the handler in the code behind:

```
protected void SubmitLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Authenticate();
}
```

`SubmitLinkButton_Click` is never called. :(

**Edit (more code):**

```
//Page_Init on the Master page
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
        try
        {

            if (SessionFacade.User != null)
            {
                loginlabel.Text = "Logged in |";
                LoginLink.Visible = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            CacheFacade.RemoveSessionValues();
            Session.Abandon();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loginlabel.Text = "";
        LoginLink.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**Page_Load** on the ASPX page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack.Equals(false))
    {
        /* Some business stuff that boils down to this: */
        Session["company"] = Request["company"];
    }
}
```

**Page_Load** on the Login Control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //honestly, there's no code here
    }

}
```

**P.S**: I need to keep the non-url-rewrite way of accessing the login page, because many users are still navigating to that URL.

**P.P.S**: Even if URL rewriting isn't enabled, the error still occurs.

Comment: you don't have any onClientClick scripts running?

Comment: Nope! As a quick update, I traced the POST request and the response. The post from my client seems fine. In response, the server is simply resending the login page, which is consistent with the server-side behaviour I'm seeing.

Comment: Could you please show us the complete code?

Comment: Regarding `/* Some business stuff that boils down to this: */ Session["company"] = Request["company"];` I hope that is psuedo code, because trusting raw input from an HTTP request is a dangerous security issue.

Comment: The included code contains no errors from what I can tell. Your error could be due to your rewrite, web.config, IIS settings, and/or other interactions that are causing the problem. We'll need more code and config settings to be able to help you.

Comment: @Jon Adams, yeah don't worry that's pseduo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I've seen this problem in the past it has usually been attributed to URL re-writing. I would usually reach for [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to trace the HTTP activity. My hunch tells me after you click the button and see the POST request it will quickly be followed up by a 302 redirect to the login page.

You note that "The above failure occurs when using this parameter" of the login.aspx page. Are you certain there is no url-rewriter configuration that for example, may strip out any querystring values and do a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check your caching policy. Possibly your request is cached

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the history on my IE browser and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use a different browser? Once I had a similar problem, and it solved by re-installing Firefox!